# Using DrawerLayout with Fragments and getting up navigation working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am using a `DrawerLayout` as the way to navigate the various screens of my app. I have a few different items in the drawer such as:

- News
- Photos
- Events
- Menu

Each one of those is a `Fragment` (mostly `ListFragment`), and then you can navigate deeper by tapping a row in the list to take you to another `Fragment`. E.g., seeing a list of photo galleries, then tapping one of them and it will show the photos.

I am able to tap the drawer icon or slide from the left to show the drawer and choose any of the options and it will correctly show that `Fragment`. But, when I go into a deeper fragment (going to photos then tapping a gallery to see the list of photos) the drawer icon does not change to a back icon and allow the user to navigate back to the previous `Fragment`. I can tap the hardware back button and it will go back, but not with the button.

In my `MainActivity` I have:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

In `Photos`, when tapping a row that represents a gallery I have:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        PUCObjects.PUCPhotoGalleryItem item = items.get(position);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

        PUCPhotosGridFragment newFragment = new PUCPhotosGridFragment();
        newFragment.galleryId = item.assetId;

        ft.add(R.id.container_frame, newFragment, ""+position);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        // Start the animated transition.
        ft.commit();

    }//end

});
```

And then when it loads list the list of photos `Fragment`, in `onActivityCreated():

```
// Show loading view
MainActivity main = (MainActivity)getActivity();
main.showLoadingActivity(true);

// Show the back button
main.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**How can I get up navigation working and show the back button when I am in deeper `Fragments`? What have I missed that will allow me to navigate back up the stack?**

Comment: the navigation drawer icon is put in place of the up arrow, you cannot have both

Comment: @tyczj I realize that. I am asking what I need to do to show the back button and have it actually go back up the stack when tapped just like the user would expect.

Comment: @NicHubbard : Can you help me in identifying the correct approach when we are moving deep down to fragment i.e. backstack contains number of fragments and when we press <- arrow fragment which is on top of back stack will pop up and shown in the screen